# html2pdf / jspdf footer not showing properly

Tags: jspdf, html2pdf

Trying to get a footer to show up using html2pdf.  Pretty standard code using what I found on Github, SO and others.

```
document.getElementById('generate').onclick = function () {

    var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');

    var opt = {
    margin:       0.5,
    filename:     '@pdf_filename',
    pagebreak:    { mode: 'avoid-all' },
    image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
    jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };



html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toPdf().get('pdf').then((pdf) => {
    var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();

    for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        pdf.setPage(i);
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
        pdf.setTextColor(150);
        pdf.text('PageNum ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 115, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 10);
    }                 

}).save();
```

The problem is the footer doesn't appear on the PDF.  I know it's somewhere in the file because if I search on "PageNum", I get hits but no display.

If I take out the line `jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }` the footer will appear fine but there will be a weird pagination issue and pages (2,3,4++) won't have correct margins.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez0mx89w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I figured out my problem.  The jsPDF unit is set to 'in' but my footer calculations are assuming 'px' (getWidth() - 115).  I just tweaked the calculations to something like getWidth() - 5 and it worked